# How to save the clang AST?

Tags: c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on some project which needs to using the AST of c code. And i am thinking about using the clang. Such as,

```
clang -Xclang -ast-dump file_name.c
```

```
clang -Xclang -ast-print file_name.c
```

However, those command only can print the ast to the command. How can i save the AST as a file, such as .xml?

Comment: how about piping the output to a file?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it targets a common issue, redirecting.

Answer (score 2):

libclang allows you to save a parsed translation unit into a serialized representation that can later be read back into memory. Have a look at [clang_saveTranslationUnit](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TRANSLATION__UNIT.html#ga3abe9df81f9fef269d737d82720c1d33) and [clang_parseTranslationUnit2](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TRANSLATION__UNIT.html#ga2baf83f8c3299788234c8bce55e4472e). Similar tools exist for Python bindings.

Comment: This approach is better because it saves it in structuralized format. Later you can load it using any language that support clang bindings. Why is it not marked as the answer?